# Microsoft OAuth2 login implementation - req.query is empty in callback

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication

I am trying to implement Microsoft Authentication using Microsoft Graph Client. I have given http://localhost:3000/callback as a redirect_uri. I am handing the '/callback' route in node.js app.

On successful login, i am hitting the node.js '/callback' route. When i try to get 'req.query.code' or 'req.query.state', I am getting undefined.

Update: looks like, on successful login I am redirected to the http://localhost:300/callback, but after the 'callback' there is '#code=SOMECODE&state=STATE' (notice #). It should be "?". How to get question mark, please help me.

Thank you